# MYSQL Workbech connection to local network database?

Tags: mysql, workbench

I'm trying to setup a new connection in `MySQL Workbench` to `MySQL` server on my other network computer named say: `SERVER`

`Hostname: SERVER`

```
Port:3306
```

Username and password I leave blank.

I'm getting `"unknown server host"`

`SERVER` has dynamic IP.

How do I provide the correct `Hostname`?

Comment: have you tried passing the actual ip address as host?

Comment: have you checked firewall settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can connect to a computer of your network with its name only in MySQL Workbench.

So, if you can't allocate a fixed IP with DHCP to your computer running MySQL maybe you could use port forwarding in your router config (localhost:port -> computer2_ip:mysql_port) so you will be able to connect to localhost:port in MySQL Workbench. You could also create a tunnel between the two computer but I think this is rather a question for ServerFault.